# PayPal "Buy Now" transactions

Tags: php, paypal

Last 15 days trying to solved paypal problem, after PayPal upgrade my customers have problem make payments, first few days it worked fine from time to time but now only showing error.

After I choose item to buy and click Buy Now button paypal show me

> "This transaction is invalid. Please return to the recipient's website
>   to complete your transaction using their regular checkout flow."
>   here is image http://screencast.com/t/YJycxzb0FGkf

When I change

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
```

to

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donation">
```

than it work for some customers but not for all as beffore. Are I need done some PHP upgrade after paypal upgrade ?

my html code on button click

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td height="10">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><div style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;margin:0px 5px 15px 5px">Recharge your Knight Cash</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><div style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;margin:0px 5px 15px 5px">Processing payment... please wait.</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <div style="font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;margin:0px 5px 15px 5px">
                <form action="https://www<%PAYPAL-SANDBOX%>.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" id="payment_form" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<%PAYPAL-ADDRESS%>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<%strName%>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<%nPrice%>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="tax" value="0.00">
                    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
                    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
                    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="<%CURRENCY%>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<%TRANSACTION-ID%>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<%SERVER-URL%>/index.php?page=store&act=recharge&subact=success&id=<%TRANSACTION-ID%>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<%SERVER-URL%>/index.php?page=store&act=recharge&subact=cancel&id=<%TRANSACTION-ID%>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<%SERVER-URL%>/index.php?page=store&act=recharge&subact=ipn&txid=<%TRANSACTION-ID%>">
                    <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">

                </form>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    document.getElementById('payment_form').submit();
                </script>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

are I maybe missing something ? Last 5 years it worked fine no problem, so maybe need upgrade script. Any suggestion is welcome because I tryed many things and nothing dosent help.

thanks in advance

Comment: In SendBox mode work perfect without error as was work beffore on live mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting PayPal thay say working on fix Buy Now buttons. Hope it will help someone to dont try fix problem as I do and waste time so only need wait until paypal solved problem.

> Thank you for contacting PayPal regarding the difficulties your
>   customers have been experiencing when trying to sen payments to your
>   PayPal account.
>
> Good morning Mr. Flegy. My name is Rafaela and I am happy to resolve
>   your query today.
>
> I regret for the inconvenience you have experienced. I have carefully
>   reviewed your email along with the information on your PayPal account
>   and it seems that it has been affected by a known technical issue that
>   has already been reported with our engineering team.
>
> We are aware of an issue with the Buy Now button and the root cause of
>   it has already been resolved. We are now working hard to fix each and
>   every account affected by it.
>
> Mr. Flegy, thank you for providind us the html code and the
>   screenshot.
>
> Regretabbly, we cannot open links or email attachments due to security
>   reasons. So I would like to kindly request you send the screenshot
>   using the link below:
>
> http://www.paypal.com/va/cardconfirmfail/
>
> This will help us to fix this situation.
>
> Thank you very much for your patience and in the meantime you can send
>   your buyers a Money Request or an Invoice.
>
> You can send a Money Request to anyone with an email address. When
>   the Money Request is paid, the money is added to your PayPal account
>   balance.
>
> Here’s how to send a Money Request:
>
> Go to www.paypal.com and log in to your account. Click ‘Request Money’
>   near the top of the page. Complete the form and click ‘Continue.’
>   Review your request and click ‘Request Money.’ Note:
>
> We email the recipient your Money Request. We email you when the Money
>   Request is paid. Here’s how to send an Invoice:
>
> PayPal's Invoicing Tool lets you send professional business invoices
>   through email, to use your PayPal account to send an invoice, please
>   follow these steps:
>
> Log in to your account at http://www.paypal.com/ Click on ‘Request
>   Money’ near the top of the page. You can choose to ‘Create an Invoice’
>   by clicking on this option near the top of the page. Choose ‘New
>   Invoice’ from the ‘Select Template’ drop down list and click
>   ‘Continue’ to start using the invoice tool. Complete the form with the
>   requested information and click ‘Continue’. Review the confirmation
>   screen and click ‘Send Invoice’. The recipient will receive an email
>   informing them of your request for payment which contains a link.
>   After clicking the link, the recipient can log into their existing
>   PayPal account, sign up for a new account or enter their credit card
>   information to pay the money request. Once the recipient pays you, the
>   money will appear in your PayPal account balance.
>
> I believe that the information that I have provided resolves your
>   query. However, please do not hesitate to contact us if you require
>   any further information and we will be more than happy to resolve it
>   for you. Have a good day Mr. Flegy.
>
> It is my pleasure to assist you. Thank you for choosing PayPal.
>
> Sincerely, Rafaela  PayPal
>
> Copyright © 1999-2016 PayPal. All rights reserved. Consumer advisory-
>   PayPal Pte. Ltd., the holder of PayPal’s stored value facility, does
>   not require the approval of the Monetary Authority of Singapore. Users
>   are advised to read the terms and conditions carefully.